# Code with Task.Run changes output when debugger is attached

Tags: c#, debugging, task-parallel-library

I have the following sample program:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackoverflowExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static int value = 1;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (value == 1)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    value = 2;
                }
            });

            Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                value = 3;
            });

            Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect this code to output `2`. I thought `t1` would see the value is `1`, then sleep for a second in which time `t2` sets the value to `3` and then `t1` changes it back to `2`.

This is the behavior that happens when the debugger is attached (hitting F5 in Visual Studio). However, when I run this program without the debugger attached (Ctrl + F5 in Visual Studio), the output is `3`.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t2` is starting before `t1`, so that `if (value == 1)` returns false.

There is no guarantee that threads will start in order.

Comment: Other way around: t2 starts before t1 when *not* running under the debugger (if I understand the OP correctly).

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why t2 couldn't start running before t1. With the TPL library it's even the more likely scenario (the tasks being pushed on a LIFO stack first).

The debugger can delay/change things enough to produce another result.

Tasks and threading can often be misleading this way.

Comment: As far as I know, in TPL, each thread pool thread has its own local LIFO queue and there is also a global FIFO queue. Since the main thread is not a thread pool thread, both `Task`s will go to the global FIFO queue.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know about the LIFO/FIFO difference between the Task schedulers

Answer (score 0):

You have what is called a "[Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)". You have two actions that can take a indeterminate amount of time, and depending on who starts/finishes first you get a different result.

To avoid situations like these you need to make sure your code uses waits in the appropriate places when you are working with multiple threads.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackoverflowExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static AutoResetEvent sequenceLock = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        static int value = 1;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (value == 1)
                {
                    sequenceLock.Set(); //lets t2 past the WaitOne()
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    value = 2;
                }
            });

            Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                sequenceLock.WaitOne(); //Waits for t1 to set the flag.
                value = 3;
            });

            Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than using an `AutoResetEvent`, if you're going to use the TPL, it would make sense to use a TPL style of programming.  In this case it would mean setting tasks as continuations of each other to indicate the desired dependencies.

Comment: @Servy makes A good point, I was just trying to demonstrate the concept of synchronization with the minimal changes to the original code to help make a point. The way I did this is by no way the "correct" way to handle this if this was the final code, but I assumed you made a simplified example for this site and the real code that prompted this had many things running before and after the "sync point" that must happen in order.